# $.getJSON() not working in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

This is truly weird and I do not know where I am going wrong.

Here's my controller:

```
    namespace MvcAJAX.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }        

        public ActionResult Called()
        {
            var retObject = new { rollNo = 2, name = "Deepanjan" };
            return Json(retObject);

        }
    }    
}
```

Here's my Index View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<script>
    /// <reference path="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js" />
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#button1').click(function () {
            $.getJSON("/Home/Called",function () {
                alert('Working!');
                $('#p1').text("Roll Number was " + data.rollNo + " and the Name was " + data.name);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<h1>This page demos Load with callback function!</h1>
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Click Me!"/><br />
<p style="height:200px" id="p1"></p>
<hr />
```

My getJSON simply doesn't work & I do not even get the alert. What's wrong?

Comment: Check your browser console for any errors. Did you check whether the click event is called?

Comment: Try replacing `return Json(retObject);` with `return Json(retObject,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you include jquery file?? Jquery file has to first than you can write your own javascript codes..

and try this codes;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#button1').click(function () {
        $.getJSON("/Home/Called", function (retObject) {
            alert('Working!');
            $('#p1').text("Roll Number was " + retObject.rollNo + " and the Name was " + retObject.name);
        });
    });
});
```

Try replacing `return Json(retObject);` with `return Json(retObject,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Answer (score 1):

Try an Ajax post from view , like this

```
 $.ajax({
 url: '@Url.Action(action)',
  data: data
  type: 'POST',
  success: function (result) {

                              }
                          });
```

Answer (score 0):

---

***> only write in your Mvc controller function this line

> Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
>
> ---